# why 'Sizeof' value differs from the number of bytes before the flexible-length member of a struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

```
typedef struct {

/*has 15 pointers*/ // ==> 15 x 4 = 60 bytes ;

uint16_t;           // ==>           2 bytes

uint16_t array[];
} dummy_struct;
```

CASE-A) `sizeof(dummy_struct)` returns 64 bytes

CASE-B) while if I try to print,

`((int) &(((dummy_struct *)(0))->array[0]))` this prints 62 bytes.

This prints 62 bytes as well: `((int) &(((dummy_struct *)(0))->array))`

I don't understand why there is a change in value? Shouldn't `sizeof()` return 62 as well?

If there's padding of those 2 extra bytes, shouldn't it happen before the flexible-length member in the struct? If that's the case, shouldn't CASE-B print 64 too instead of 62?

EDIT:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t temp;
    uint8_t array[][6];
} dummy2;
         printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(dummy2), offsetof(dummy2, array));  // PRINTS 4 4
         printf("%d \n",((int) &(((dummy2 *)(0))->array[0])));   // PRINTS 4
```

How come this same effect is not happening with the previous example? Padding doesn't seem to happen here. So, the possible reason for the previous example is padding happening after the flexible-size member?

Comment: That's a flexible array member, not a VLA. A VLA is an array with a non-constant length; it can't be a member of a struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` returns the size of the entire structure, while your other two expressions return the offset of the `array` member, which happens to be two bytes before the end of the `struct`. You can get the same result with the `offsetof`, like this:

```
offsetof(dummy_struct, array) // This is 62
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Xo2jq8)

Comment: So, sizeof returns 64 (62+2) as the padding is happening after the array member?

Comment: @M10TheMist Yes, that's padding after the array, because adding an extra `uint_16` member before the `array` does not change the size of the `dummy_struct` ([demo](http://ideone.com/9SUV48)). That's the reason the effect does not happen in your second example: `uint32_t` does not force the padding of the `struct`'s size.

Answer (score 1):

The padding probably does not come before the dummy array, because the dummy array doesn't need it, since the type is `uint16_t`, which presumably only needs 2-byte alignment, not 4.

That said, I bet this is highly implementation- and target-dependent.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Shouldn't the VLA be the last member in the struct and if any padding happened it should've happened before VLA as the size of VLA is unknown at compile time?

Comment: What I'm guessing is that the compiler looked at the type of the VLA element (`uint16_t`) and decided since it's already on a 2-byte boundary no padding is needed for it.  Then however when closing up the structure, it rounds up the size to a multiple of 4.  Try changing the VLA to `uint32_t array[]` and you'll see it will then put padding in front of the VLA to put it on a 4-byte boundary.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a VLA, it's a flexible array member.  A VLA can only be a automatic variable (i.e a regular variable on the stack), not the member of a struct.  This is because lots of things the compiler does depend on knowing the size of the elements it manipulates.

Based on your comment, it looks like you're on a 32-bit platform which has 4-byte alignment requirement for pointers and 2-byte alignment for 16-bit integers.  That's why you get a sizeof of 64 bytes.  For sizeof purpose, it is like there is no flexible  array member in your struct, so we can ignore it for now.  The flexible array member is a "fake" member, it does not take any space.

The compiler adds 2 bytes of padding after the uint16_t to guarantee that in an array of dummy_struct the pointers have 32-bit alignment.  Imagine an array of 2 dummy structs, if there is no padding, the first pointer would start right after the uint16_t and it would not be aligned on a 32-bit boundary.

Note that you can usually force the compiler not to pad, but there is no portable way for doing this.  With gcc for example, you can use `attribute ((packed))` on the struct.  If you do that, sizeof(dummy_struct) will return 62 bytes.

For B, you're basically printing the offset of the flexible array member.  The C99 standard says:

*As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply. However, when a . (or ->) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past it.*

So when you use ->, the FAM behaves like it's a regular array with the biggest size it could have without changing the size reported by sizeof (64 bytes).  In this case, you can only fit a single 16-bit integer without changing the size.  In this imaginary struct, there would be no padding and the offset of the imaginary array of one element would be 62 (right after the uint16_t).  So that's why you get 62.

If your FAM was a int32_t, you could fit 0 element without changing the size (you'd need the 2 bytes of padding to do the alignment).  The standard says that this behaves like an array of size 1.  So your FAM will be at offset 64 like what sizeof return.

Let me re-iterate: if you simply change `int16_t array[]` into `int array[]`, A) will still return 64 but B) will now return 64, not 62.

This is also what happens in your second example.  Your FAM is now an array of pointers.  You're on a 32-bit platform and your struct is 4.  You can fit 0 element in the FAM without changing the size.  So its offset is 4.

Comment: Is there any clean portable way of finding out how many bytes would have to be allocated for a structure with some number of items in a FAM?  Should one add the offset of the FAM to the size of the items therein, and then round the result based upon the __alignof() of the structure?

Comment: I think you just have to do sizeof(dummy) - the offset of the FAM + sizeof(FAM type) * number of elements in your FAM.
If you start doing things like this though, you probably want to have a packed structure (no padding by the compiler).  Then it gets trivial to allocate it.  You have to ensure proper alignment for your types though.  On x86, the architecture does deal with misaligned stuff but that does have performance and semantics consequences (for example loading a 32-bit number could not be atomic)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of the flexibly array member, assuming the system requires 32-bit alignment for 32-bit integers, the size of the struct would be 64 bytes, including two bytes of padding at the end.  If one were to add a fixed-size array holding an even number of 16-bit values, the size of the struct would grow by the size of the added items.

While one could make the argument that code which uses a struct with a flexible array member will know if it needs to adjust the computed size of an item to ensure that consecutively-stored items have proper alignment, and thus `sizeof()` should report the size of the portion of the structure prior to the flexible member, having the addition of an array reduce the reported size of a structure would be "surprising" behavior.  Arguably, the proper way for the language to handle the situation would be to have `sizeof` require the specification of a second parameter giving the number of items in the array in which case `sizeof(dummy_struct,1)` would yield 64 but `sizeof(dummy_struct,2)` would yield 68.